# Confirming a GPG key as mine

Tags: macos, gnupg

I imported a public/private key pair generated on my desktop into my laptop. Now however I get this issue when I try to encrypt a file for my own use:

```
gpg -e -r "Jonathan Max Barnes" random-text-file
gpg: C1E2B437: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user

pub  4096R/C1E2B437 2013-09-06 Jonathan Max Barnes (Jonny) <jonny@jonnybarnes.net>
 Primary key fingerprint: B068 1437 14F5 2628 5404  92FE 6C13 E65E CABC 1625
      Subkey fingerprint: 6F61 DBBA A310 B7D6 4E87  7409 C71A C485 C1E2 B437

It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing,
you may answer the next question with yes.

Use this key anyway? (y/N)
gpg: random-text-file: encryption failed: Unusable public key #obviously pressing y forces gpg to encrypt
```

I am certain the key is my key, how can I tell gpg this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try trusting the public key:

```
gpg --edit-key "Jonathan Max Barnes"
```

then at `Command>` prompt type

```
trust
```

then answer `4` for `fully` to the resulting question.

Details [here](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html)

Comment: This has worked, gpg will now encrypt files for my use.

Answer (score 6):

If you import a key generated on another computer, you still have to put ultimate trust on it. From [A GnuPG tutorial](http://www.queen.clara.net/pgp/art4.html):

> In contrast with PGP and with early versions of GnuPG, ultimate trust is not automatically assigned to your own public key - it must be set by the user. If no ultimate trust is set, the web of trust will not work, and GnuPG will report that the ownership of a key has not been validated even if you have signed that key with your own key.

There are different trust levels, each of them has a number attached:

```
1 = I don't know or won't say
2 = I do NOT trust
3 = I trust marginally
4 = I trust fully
5 = I trust ultimately
```

Trust levels three and four are used in the web of trust, to allow your verifiable set of keys to transiently spread by extending it with the signed keys of other trusted and **valid** keys (you might trust Phil Zimmermann, the inventor of PGP, to to a good job at signing other keys, but if you do not have a signature path to his key, his signatures would be worthless anyway). **Trust level 5, "ultimate trust", is different and should only be used (but should be!) for your own keys: it is allowed to introduce trust** into the web of trust, other keys (and documents/mails) signed by this key are always valid; no matter whether there is a trust path or not. Applying lower trust levels would prevent the web of trust calculation to work properly. If it works anyway, you also signed the key with another, ultimately trusted one.

By running `gpg --edit-key [keyid]`, then `trust` you can choose the trust level of a key.